# What is function $f$ is surjective, holomorphic and $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ and some other property?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, roots

What is function $f$ is surjective, holomorphic and $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}\space$  where $f(n)=0$ if and only if $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

The set $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disk where all points $m$ are in $\mathbb{D}$ when $|m|<1$

I was thinking about $\sqrt{x}$ where not all outputs are possible. Like $-1=\sqrt{y}$ doesn't exist because $1$ is defined to be there. So I was looking for a function where all of the outputs are in the unit disk. I also didn't want it to be inversible so I added at least one output to appear infinitely many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function $f$ is holomorphic and $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$, then $f$ is constant.  [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis))